# Confusion about the origin variable in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

The following code doesn't work in Chrome, but it work in Firefox

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <button onclick="origin.haha()">This is a test button</button>
        </main> 
        <script>
            A = {
                haha: function() {
                    alert(5);
                }
            }
        </script>

        <script>
            var origin = A;
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

When I click the button, I was expected to see the alert message, but when I open the code in chrome, and click button, it raise an error which said that the `origin.add` is not a function, I have check it, and I think it was because that `origin` variable is a builtin variable, and it's identified to `window.origin`.  And chrome doesn't allow user redefined the variable.

But when I open chrome debug console, and enter `origin.haha()`, it can show the alert message...

And which make me more confusing, the following code can work in chrome.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <button onclick="testFunc()">This is a test button</button>
        </main> 
        <script>
            A = {
                haha: function() {
                    alert(5);
                }
            }
        </script>

        <script>
            var origin = A;

            testFunc = function() {
                origin.haha();
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me that what happened to the origin variable?  Why chrome can show alert message in the 2nd code but can't show alert message in the 1st code?

I wish that I have describe the question clearly...

Comment: [`window.origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/origin) is already something, avoid this variable name. Not sure why chrome decides to use this instead of looking to what the current value is though...

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for your comment, but I'm curious about it, is there any to ask Chrome team for the reason?  I have try to ask on the google chrome forum, but can't get any information about it..